# Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations

Tags: natbib, ieee-style

I am having a problem with my references, the error message is

> Bibliography not compatible with author-year citations.

I have stripped down all tex and references files however I still have the same problem.

I have tried the following:

- Delete all the temp file. I am using WinEdt8
- I have year in my reference
- Using `\citet` instead of `\cite`
- Try `\usepackage[square,sort,comma,numbers]{natbib}`

It will be much help you can help point out where did I went wrong :(

Here are the content of the files

`.tex` file:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
Text here

\citet{Ioannou2001}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{reference}

\end{document}
```

`.bib` file (with only one record)

```
    @ARTICLE{Ioannou2001,
      author = {Ioannou, G and Kritikos, M and Prastacos, G},
      title = {A greedy look-ahead heuristic for the vehicle routing problem with
  time windows},
      journal = {J Oper Res Soc},
      year = {2001},
      volume = {52},
      pages = {523--537},
      number = {5},
      month = apr,
      __markedentry = {[duongh:6]},
      issn = {0160-5682},
      owner = {d},
      publisher = {Palgrave Publishers Ltd},
      timestamp = {2013.03.29},
      url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1057/palgrave.jors.2601113}
    }
```

Comment: The problem is with the use of `IEEEtrans` style which produces `\bibitem`s that are not compatible with the `natbib` style.  In addition `IEEEtrans` is a numeric citation format.

Answer (score 10):

The bibliography style `IEEtran` was developed for the class `IEEEtran`. All the settings are done for the Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers. By default there is no compatibility for `natbib`. However the authors of `IEEtran` provides an extra bibliography style which is compatible with `natbib` and provides the same formatting as `IEEtran`. This style is called `IEEEtranN`. As the default style the style `IEEEtranN` is a numerical style and so you need the option `numbers` for the package `natbib`. The example below uses `IEEEtranN` and results to

> [image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{reference.bib}
@ARTICLE{Ioannou2001,
      author = {Ioannou, G and Kritikos, M and Prastacos, G},
      title = {A greedy look-ahead heuristic for the vehicle routing problem with time windows},
      journal = {J Oper Res Soc},
      year = {2001},
      volume = {52},
      pages = {523--537},
      number = {5},
      month = apr,
      __markedentry = {[duongh:6]},
      issn = {0160-5682},
      owner = {d},
      publisher = {Palgrave Publishers Ltd},
      timestamp = {2013.03.29},
      url = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1057/palgrave.jors.2601113}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\begin{document}
Text here

\citet{Ioannou2001}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}
\bibliography{reference}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, is there something similar for amsalpha?

Comment: @yanbo: ams is really special. I don't know any supporting by ams. Maybe you can use alphadin or plainnat

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you switch to `biblatex` with `biber` as backend. Load biblatex

```
    \usepackage[%
        backend=biber,
        style=ieee,
        natbib=true,
        backref=false,
        backrefstyle=all+,
        hyperref=true,
    ]{biblatex}
```

Load your `.bib`file

```
\addbibresource{BIBFILENAME} % enter with .bib extension
```

Both in your preamble.

Then print the bibliography where you want it using

```
\nocite{*} 

\printbibliography
```

`\nocite{*}` loads all the references in your `.bib` file.

Comment: `\addbibresource` requires the extension `bib`.

Comment: My bad, changed it